# Docker not recognizing package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm, server

I am completely lost with respect to the docker filesystem. After struggling for a couple of days and reading the documentation, I still don't understand the underlying cause of this problem.

Minimum reproducible example:

docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: "3"
 services:
  web:
   build:
    context: ./webapp
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
   volumes:
   - './:/webapp'
   - '/webapp/node_modules'
   ports:
   - '3000:3000'
   stdin_open: true
```

webapp/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:fermium

#COPY scripts/ /scripts
COPY ./ /rxc-voice

COPY ./package.json /rxc-voice 

WORKDIR /rxc-voice

RUN npm install -q

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My current directory structure is as so:

```
.
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── api
├── docker-compose.yml
├── README.md
├── webapp
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── etc
│   ├── init.ts
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── scripts # used for building in other directories
    └── deploy
```

This will pull this error:

```
web_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
web_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
web_1  | npm ERR! path /rxc-voice/package.json
web_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/rxc-voice/package.json'
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent
```

when trying to run despite the fact that everything *should* be copied to the image

Ideally, the docker-compose uses the `.` context and switches pwd in the Dockerfile, but I can't get that to work either.

Interestingly, `docker build .` inside of the `webapp` directory works fine (after modifying the Dockerfile to do the same thing with different directory structure.

Comment: You're trying to cat it before copying it. Why do you need to cat it before copying?

Comment: Docker doesn't run these commands on the host. The guest context does it. The file isn't able to be called by cat until you copy it. The file system is empty until that time.

Comment: @zero298 ah, excuse me. That doesn't make much sense as a minimum reproducable, you're right. I'll edit in a bit, but the problem I'm getting to the core of is that once all of these directories are copied, docker still has a problem during the ``up`` stage; ``npm ERR! path /webapp/package.json``

Comment: `npm ERR! path /rxc-voice/package.json` is not the full error. Post the full error.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED it gives absolutely no additional information, but done.

Comment: It does, though. It proves that it is in fact an ENOENT error.

Comment: Try adding a / to the end of the destination path in your COPY.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED it pulls the same error.